# Migrating Realm with the re-creation of the schema to a specific version of the database

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-migration

Prior to the version of database 11 in my application, the user did not enter data. So I did not need migration. I used `.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()`. Starting with version 11, users can enter data. Now I need to use migration. Before version 11, I need to re-create the schema, but at the same time, starting with version 11, I need to save user data. How to do it in my custom migration class?

Also, my application uses encryption. I get the key when authorizing the application on the server when the application starts. The name of the database is also formed on the basis of this key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do in your case is delete the Realm file if it's older than version 11, and otherwise handle your migration as needed.

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                                            .schemaVersion(11)
                                            .migration(new MyMigration())
                                            ./*...*/.build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
DynamicRealm dynamicRealm = DynamicRealm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
long schemaVersion = dynamicRealm.getVersion();
dynamicRealm.close();
if(schemaVersion < 11) {
    Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfiguration);
}
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(); // should work now
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It really helped to understand the situation, but I do not want extra i/o in the place where the configuration is formed. I think about the option of deciding whether to delete the database, depending on the version of the application.

Comment: That makes sense too!